# Is it haram to call a woman/girl "angel"?

Tags: halal-haram, malaikah

Is it Haram to call a woman angel, or its mocking for the religion?

I don't mean like naming her Malk/angel, I mean to say for example this girl is like an angel, something like this.

Comment: one should NOT do this because it may be miskaten for some things mentioned in Quran where kafirs (and worse) did ascribe angels to be female while they themselves prefered males... I am no scholar but I would refrain from comparing anyone (esp. female) with an angel!

Comment: You can find a number of fatwas (in Arabic) here: http://forsanhaq.com/showthread.php?t=317665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the following fatwa](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/66084) by [Shaykh Muhammad Salih al-Munajjid](https://www.google.ca/search?q=shaykh+salih+al+munajjid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), such is an imitation of the *mushrikeen* ([who consider the angels to be female](http://quran.com/43/19)), and thus forbidden:

> الحمد لله
>   لا يجوز أن يقال عن الفتاة إنها ملاك أو تشبه الملاك ، لما في ذلك من مضاهاة المشركين الذين وصفوا الملائكة بأنهم إناث.
>   قال الله تعالى عنهم: ( وجعلوا الملائكة الذين هم عباد الرحمن إناثا أشهدوا خلقهم ستكتب شهادتهم ويسألون ) الزخرف/19 .
>   قال الشيخ بكر بن عبد الله أبو زيد حفظه الله : "أما تسمية النساء بأسماء الملائكة ؛ فظاهر الحرمة ؛ لأن فيها مضاهاة للمشركين في جعلهم الملائكة بنات الله، تعالى الله عن قولهم. وقريب من هذا تسمية البنت: ملاك، مَلَكة، ومَلَك" انتهى . "معجم المناهي اللفظية " (ص 565) .
>   وسئل الشيخ ابن عثيمين رحمه الله عن التسمي بملاك، فمنع من ذلك . "مجموع فتاوى الشيخ ابن عثيمين " (3/67) .
>   واستعمال هذا في الشعر، في وصف الفتاة أمر منكر، لا سيما إذا كان شعرا غزليا محرما، فالملائكة ( عباد مكرمون لا يعصون الله ما أمرهم ويفعلون ما يؤمرون )، ويجب تنزيههم عن مثل هذه التشبيهات والاستعارات.
>   والله أعلم.

Comment: Can you please post a translation?

Comment: I'll try my best, so `we may not call a girl/lady an _angel_ because that was/still? said by the infidels who describe angels (the real ones) as females (Sourat az-zokhrof verset 19)` English is not my native language :'(

Answer (score 2):

If you can read arabic, in this [fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=121519) they said that it is better not to call a girl by angel, and not to name it like this (angel or Malak in arabic).

However if you know a girl with this name, then you can call her if she don't want to change her name, because you will be calling her only, not intending to name her so (والله أعلم).

Answer (score -1):

it could be a guy or girl you call angelic it simply means beautiful and pure because the angels are beautiful and pure. Does not mean you are calling the angles females. You don't call someone an angel cuz they are female, you call them angels because they are beautiful. And angels worship Allah all the time, so what a beautiful thing to compare someone to.